# PHP run SQL result in another SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is this possible? I need to run the result of one sql statement into another..

```
$result= mysqli_query($dbconn,"Select max(cartid) from cart;");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$sql1 = "insert into cart(cartid) values('".$row['max(cartid)']."');";
mysqli_query($dbconn,$mysql1);
```

**EDIT:**

Added in my sql tables to show a better example of what im trying to do
This is my cart table[image]

This is my transaction table
[image]

Basically I want to transfer the row where cartid = 5 from cart table, into the transaction table where the new transaction id will be = 5. As you can see, the transaction table also has a cartid. Not sure how im going to bring over this cartid and insert into the transaction table as a new row. FYI, in order to get cartid=5 i would like to use 
`order by cartid desc limit 1` to get the last possible row in the cart table

The new transaction table's row will look something like this.

```
transactionid outletid nric cartid transactiondate totalbeforediscount totalafterdiscount transactiontime username
     5           0      0     5         0                 0                       0                 0            0
```

Comment: Is the only purpose for retrieving the data in the first query (`$result`) to then use it in the second - or - will you be using that data elsewhere as well?

Comment: @Nicarus I would also be using it elsewhere as well

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the queries into one.

Please give it a try:

`INSERT INTO cart(cartid) SELECT MAX(cartid) FROM cart`

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c630/1/0)</kbd>

**EDIT:**

In order to insert mulitiple values like that your query would look like below:

`INSERT INTO cart(cartid,rowid) SELECT MAX(cartid),MAX(rowid) FROM cart`

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f4c4a/1/0)</kbd>

*But I don't understand why are trying to insert the columns having max value in the same table. Since your table contains those already.*

**Edit2:**

`INSERT INTO transaction_table(cartid) SELECT MAX(cartid) FROM cart;`

Comment: hmm, how about if lets say i want to insert multiple values from different tables?   Maybe like this?   "Insert into cart(cartid,rowid) Select Max(cartid) from cart,Select Max(rowid) from row"

Comment: What if my rowid comes from another table? Sorry im just using an example

Comment: Then I guess you need to share actually what are you intending to do.

Comment: I will be getting a few result from some sql statements. And i want to place all these results together into one insert sql statement. So i will then be inserting values of these different results i got, into one sql table. However the results that i am getting are mostly from other tables.. Sorry if i'm not explaining it well enough. I'm not sure why the way i'm doing isnt correct, by storing each result into a PHP variable then using it in another SQL statement

Comment: Then please share the table structures of all the related tables. Without prior knowledge of which data come from which table I cannot provide any help.

Comment: Okay, i've added in screenshots of my table structure. Thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: Please also add the expected output. That means what the `transaction` table look like after having the new entry coming from `cart` table?

Comment: I've just added it in.

Comment: I've updated the answer. It will work if `transactionid` is `primary key auto_increment` and all other fields have default value. Please check and confirm.